# How to solve jQuery-File-Upload / Classic-ASP error ASP 0177 - 800401f3?

Tags: jquery, iis-7, asp-classic

I'm trying to use '[jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)' as a solution for uploading files to an `IIS/Classic ASP` application. On the jQuery-File-Upload project wiki I found out someone who did a [very good work (click here to see)](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Classic-ASP), but when I try to use is I am receiving an strange error on file `upload.asp`, line 303 as bellow:

```
'Persits ASPUpload
Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
```

[image: Image error]

Does anybody here has any idea of what is happening?

Thank you very much, and sorry for my terrible English.

Comment: Have you installed ASPUpload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the client-side jQuery "widget", apparently your server-side code relies on an ActicveX control, that needs to be registered on your server (done via its installation package or regsvr32 command). If you google "Persits.Upload", one of the results sends you to  [this website](http://www.aspupload.com/index.html), where you seem to be able to get that ActiveX. But I want to make a point, that you should only install software that you trust and that I have not used, know, endorse or recommend this ActiveX in any way, shape or form :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! It needs ASPUpload to work, and your tip made me look to another solution here, because I don't have ASPUpload.